# Can one disregard tadpole diagrams even if an operator is being inserted?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

I understand that the renormalization condition $\langle0|\phi|0\rangle=0$ permits one to disregard tadpole diagrams in most calculations due to the leg of the tadpole carrying zero momentum. **If an operator is being inserted into a diagram containing a tadpole, can one still make such a claim in general**? This affects momentum conservation in such a way, depending on whether the operator is inserted at a vertex or propagator, that tadpole diagrams seemingly have a legitimate contribution to the matrix element. An example would be a 2-point insertion in $\phi^3$ theory:

$$\int d^4z_1 d^4z_2\langle p'|\phi(x)^2\phi(z_1)^3\phi(z_2)^3|p\rangle$$

where an example contraction is the following diagram

[image]

where the black blob denotes the operator insertion. In this case, the tadpole leg does not necessarily carry zero momentum which makes me very skeptical on discarding such a diagram.

Comment: Which operator is being inserted in your 2-point example? $\phi(x)^2$?

Comment: Correct. Also derivatives $\partial^\mu_x\partial^\nu_y\phi(x)\phi(y)$ where we take the local limit $x=y$ after the derivatives have been taken. The $\phi(x)^2$ multiplies $g^{\mu\nu}$ in case you're worried about the tensor structure being inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, OP's connected diagram with the $\phi(x)^2$ operator insertion is no longer a tadpole diagram, because no matter how we cut the diagram in two by cutting a single line, each of the two connected components will still contain a source term (i.e. an operator insertion or an external line), cf. e.g. the definition given in Ref. 1.

References:

1. M. Srednicki, *QFT,* 2007; Chapter 9 see text above eq. (9.24). A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html).